# The 'Add to homescreen' link is not visible in Chrome Devtools - Application - Manifest

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to simulate the 'Add to Homescreen' event as described in [this guide from google](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/progressive-web-apps#add-to-homescreen). But, that blue link 'Add to homescreen' that they have in their screenshot under DevTools - Application - Manifest simply isn't there on my Chrome Dev Tools. I've tried it on several PWAs (including the [Google I/O 2016 progressive web app](https://events.google.com/io2016/) PWA suggested as a page to try the feature on in the first link). No luck. That link simply isn't there.

Ultimately, I want to catch the event, prevent the default and then show the user a custom 'Install this app' message, as suggested [in this guide](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/). But to test it, I need this Chrome DevTools feature.

My Chrome DevTools version is 76.

Comment: This sounds the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58128145/add-to-homescreen-link-missing-in-chrome-devtools. Per the accepted answer there, Google's documentation is obsolete: the "Add to homescreen" link was removed from DevTools.

Answer (score 0):

Link the web manifest and add a link for the website in the html file

https://openclassrooms.com/en/courses/2479876-build-your-website-with-html5-and-css3/2490386-creating-links

For example

```
<p>This is the homescreenlink <a href="http://www.homescreenlink.domainame"></a>?<br />
</p>
```

In Running the chrome development tools,

it is important to check what is the error maessage in the application list.

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/progressive-web-apps

What are the error messages you get when you work on this?
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/

One can debug with this tutorial.
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/reference